# Make bootstrap typeahead search clickable with href

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

I want to add a href "post.php?id=x" with id associated with the title.

Here my code :-

Html:

```
<input type="text" id="name" class="search" autocomplete="off" data-provide="typeahead" placeholder="search">
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#name').typeahead({
  source: function(query, result)
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"search.php",
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data)
    {
     result($.map(data, function(item){
      return item;
     }));
    }
   })
  }
 });

});
```

php - sql:

```
$array = array();
$query = $bdd->prepare("SELECT title, post_id FROM post");
$query->execute();

while($row = $query->fetch())
{
    $array[] = $row['title'];
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

I tried everything I found on stackoverflow but nothing works.. How I can do this pls?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your question completely, please describe it more, but
I suggest you add  `<form action="post.php?id=x">` and `</form>` 
So your HTML markup (can be .php) should look like:

```php
<form method="POST" acion="post.php?id=x"/> <!-- here you can echo ID from session -->
<input type="text" id="name" class="search" autocomplete="off" data-provide="typeahead" placeholder="search" />
<input type="submit" value="Search!" />
</form>
```

Btw if you dont want replace `post.php?id=x` with real id, like `post.php?id=84` you can replace `x` in your `<form>` to `<?php echo $id; ?>`
Of course you must add some PHP defining $id, but as I said, i don't understand your whole question, please describe it more so we can help you.
I hope it helps, :)
Thanks,
Oliver

Comment: thanks for help, but that's not what I'm looking for, so i have a title who has autocomplete with the typeahead library, this title belongs of a post, this post has a id, so i want when we click on the autocomplete title, we are re directed on "post.php?id=x"

Comment: Ahh I see, you can wrap autocomplete box into ```<a href="post.php?id=x">```. It will redicert you to yourdomain.com/post.php?id=x.